# Reading chinese characters into a string from a byte buffer

Tags: java, unicode, buffer, cjk

So I have a char[] array that contains text and other data.

How can I extract chinese text from the char[] array? Right now I can get english fine with

```
public String getString(int index, int length) {
    String str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < length && this.data[index + i] != 0; i++)
        str = str + this.data[index + i];

    return str;
}
```

then I'm trying this:

```
try {
    String charset = "GB18030";
    String str = new String(m.target.getBytes("UTF-16"), "GB18030");
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str.equals("大家"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

m.target is a string i've gotten from the byte[] array with getString() above. I've tried various encodings and combinations of them and none of them will display the text correctly (大家) and none will return true for str.equals("大家")

**EDIT**

Using this method i can successfully get the chinese characters.

```
public String test(int index, int length) {
    byte[] t = new byte[this.data.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++)
        t[i] = (byte) this.data[i];

    try {
        return new String(t, index, length, "GB18030");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

But my question now is.. I thought the max a byte could be was 127? How can the byte array hold the high byte chinese characters? Can I safely change the buffer to byte[] instead of char[]?

Comment: Why are you using both `"UTF-16"` and `"GB18030"`? Why not just do: `new  String(this.data, offset, length, "UTF-16")`?

Comment: I mistakenly said i was using a byte[] array for this.data. It's actually a character array. If it was a byte[] array wouldn't it not be able to hold unicode text? As the highest value a byte can hold is 127?

Comment: A `char[]` would contain text in UTF-16 code units. A `byte[]` could contain text in any encoding as text encodings are nothing more than a way of mapping character numbers to bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Both **char** and **String** in Java are Unicode. You don't have to care about this as long as you operate on it inside Java code. You specify encoding while converting to/from **byte[]** array or read/write to/from **IO stream**.

To declare String containing chinese characters you can use escaped sequences or just write them in code, but you must care then about file encoding. **UTF-8** format is quasi-standard nowadays, it is supported by both IDE's (such as Eclipse) and build tools (maven, ant).

So you just write

```
char ch = '大';
char[] chrs = new char[]{'大','家'};
String str = "大家";
```

To read chinese characters from for example **UTF-16** encoded file, you use **InputStreamReader** specifying proper encoding, and you can read then strings, f.e. with help of **BufferedReader**

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"), "UTF-16"));
```